# Issue trying to calculate average with javascript method

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to calculate average score from an array of objects, for some reason I'm getting the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: discountReviews[i] is undefined"
```

I'm using a simple for in my method to calculate average:

```
getAverage: function(discount){


        let discountReviews = discount.discountreviews;

        if(discountReviews.length == 0){
            return 5;
        }
        else{
            let total = 0;
            console.log(discountReviews.length);
            for(var i=0; i<= discountReviews.length; i++){
                total = parseInt(total) + parseInt( discountReviews[i].rating);
            }

            let average = Math.ceil(total / discountReviews.length);

            return average;

        }

    },
```

My discountreviews array looks like this:

[image]

Comment: `<=` -> `<` since Arrays are 0-based in javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0; i<= discountReviews.length; i++){
    total = parseInt(total) + parseInt( discountReviews[i].rating);
}
```

The javascript use 0-based counter. So if the length of discountReviews is 1, the last circulation will calculate `discountReviews[1]` which is undefined. So change the code to

```
for(var i=0; i < discountReviews.length; i++){
    total = parseInt(total) + parseInt( discountReviews[i].rating);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `for loop`:

```
for(var i=0; i < discountReviews.length; i++){
```

`i` cannot be equal to the array length, array will go out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are zero-based index.

```
 i <= discountReviews.length
    ^
```

Remove the equal symbol

```
 i < discountReviews.length
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop will be iterating one more time than needed, and accessing the nth+1 index, which will be undefined.

try changing it to

```
for(var i=0; i < discountReviews.length; i++){
  total = parseInt(total) + parseInt( discountReviews[i].rating);
}
```